# Converting an array to int/float

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I need to convert a char array into int and float using C
The array is like this

```
char* text = "15.34";
```

I also need to convert a float/int back into an array again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sscanf also. For example:

> float fp = 0; sscanf( text, "%f", &fp
>   );

To convert back use sprintf()

Comment: One should check sscanf's return value to make sure it successfully converted the string into a float, too.

Answer (score 7):

Use `atoi()`/`strtol()` and `atof()`/`strtod()` library functions to convert from string.

To convert back use `sprintf()` with `%d` and `%f` format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `sscanf()` and `sprintf().`